# Japanese Text not writable

Tags: fonts, errors, miktex, languages, cjk

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%...
\usepackage{CJK}
\newcommand{\jap}[1]{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}#1\end{CJK}}
%...
\begin{document}
%...
\jap{よろしくお願いします}
%...
\end{document}
```

This gives error

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `C70/min/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `C70/song/m/n' instead on input line 12.

(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\cjk\UTF8\c70song.fd)
! Undefined control sequence.
try@size@range ...extract@rangefontinfo font@info 
                                                  <-*>@nil <@nnil 
l.12 \jap{よろしくお願いします}
```

The entire log-file is [here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/download/file.php?id=7124).

Strangely enough, it works when I run the code on say [WriteLaTeX](https://www.writelatex.com/259247djwnxs).

I would appreciate any and all help in resolving this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be down a missing file in MiKTeX. On my TeX Live system, the document compiles fine with a file list

```
scrreprt.cls    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script document class (report)
scrkbase.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent ba
sics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2012/06/15 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2012/04/04 v3.10b KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (type area)
inputenc.sty    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   babel.sty    2013/05/16 v3.9f The Babel package
 english.ldf    2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system
 germanb.ldf    2008/06/01 v2.6m German support from the babel system
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
     CJK.sty    2012/05/07 4.8.3
 MULEenc.sty    2012/05/07 4.8.3
  c70min.fd    2012/05/07 4.8.3
  c70min.fdx    2012/05/07 4.8.3
```

where the final two files are in `tex/latex/cjk/contrib/wadalab/c70min.fd`. With MiKTeX on the other hand I get the same error as in the question. The [CTAN directory for `CJK`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/language/chinese/CJK) seems to contain the appropriate files, so a [local installation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex) should be possible. However, I think this should also be reported to Christian Schenk as I don't see why there is the discrepancy with TeX Live.